# Integrate an if-else loop for a wordpress custom field script

Tags: php, wordpress

I search a lot, but I don´t finde the right solution.

I have a custome field, called "My-Name". This custome field can be added at a post (more then once) or not.

```
$my_name = get_post_custom_values( 'My-Name' );
foreach ( $my_name as $my_name )
echo $my_name;
```

**My problem** - if this key is not available at a post, I get an Error (Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()).

I dont want this Error-Message, I want an "else = html text" if the key isn´t available at this post. I try some if / else, but my php skills are too low for a sucess. Can someone help me?

UPDATE:
I have modify the script from dingo_d and now it works - thx!

```
$my_name = get_post_custom_values( 'My-Name' );

if(is_array($my_name) && !empty($my_name)){
    foreach($my_name as $my_name){
    echo $my_name . "\n";
    }
} else{
    echo 'My text';
}
```

Comment: Why is your array expression the same as the value?  You can make sure that the `$my_name` variable that holds an array exists by wrapping the `foreach` in an expression that checks it: `if(is_array($my_name) && !empty($my_name)){foreach($my_name as $value){echo $value;}}`

Comment: @dingo_d Interesting, I try it ... one moment.

Comment: @Pepe Seems like I wasn't paying proper attention when I made my answer, so I deleted it since to make my answer work would just make it the same as the other answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $my_name = get_post_custom_values( 'My-Name' );

 if(isset($my_name))
  {
    foreach ( $my_name as $my_name ){
      echo $my_name;
    }
  }else{
   echo "html goes here";
  }
```

Comment: Thx for support - your solution is more elegant then my and works well!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what get_post_custom_values() will return on a missing POST param, just check for the parameter being set or empty:

```
if (isset($my_name))
{
    foreach(...) ...
}
```

vs.

```
if (!empty($my_name))
{
    foreach(...) ...
}
```

By the way: An if-else-construct is not a loop ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Always check if your variable is filled with something before entering the foreach loop. That also depends on the type of return you expect as well. I'd do something like:

```
if(is_array($my_name) && !empty($my_name)){
    foreach($my_name as $value){
        echo $value;
    }
} else{
    echo 'My text';
}
```

This is because your `$my_name` variable *should* return an array. Should your return value be string you'd check if it's set and if it's not an empty string with

```
if(isset($my_variable) && $my_variable != ''){...}
```

Comment: I think this will not work with wordpress "custom fields"? Something like "get_post_custom_values" is missed, right?

Comment: What do you mean missed? You pull the `get_post_custom_values()` in your variable `$my_names`.

Comment: Sry, I saw your updated script after my comment - I try your one but I get an error "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context"

Comment: I edited the code out, don't try to see if it's set. That's why the fatal error. Just try the first loop.

Comment: The best way to debug your code is to `print_r()` the variables along the way to see what the return is. So first try printing out what the return for `$my_name` variable is. It should be an array so you can enter a foreach if it is an array and if it's not empty. Then inside foreach you can print out what the `$value` variable is. That's the safest way to see what you're getting out. Once you've found out what you need, delete the `print_r()` functions from your code. Also can you update your question so that we can see the contents of that variable?

Comment: I try your updated script and it works, if no custom field with this key is available, otherwise the page get distroyed with blank space.

Comment: I print_r() it and get the value - just some names, which are postet in the custome fields, so the variable works - right?